# Running OCR Python

Tags: python, ocr

[image]I am trying to make some OCR with Python. I found this code on the internet, which did what I want to. But when I try to run it, I receive this error message.

Leave my code Here:

```
import io 
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
pdf = wi(filename="test1(citibank).pdf", resolution=300)
pdfImage = pdf.convert('jpeg')
imageBlobs = []

for img in pdfImage.sequence:
    imgPage=wi(image=img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

recognisedtext = []

for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='es')
    recognisedtext.append(text)

print(recognisedtext[1])
```

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Just Posted The Error

Comment: Looks like it's having trouble running ghostscript. First things first - can you confirm that you've installed gs? And if so, does it work from a normal command prompt to type `gs -h`?

Comment: Edit the *text* of the error message into your question, not a picture of it.

Comment: I do have it, but my computer doesn't recognise gs

Comment: You may need to add the executable to your path variable then. This is covered in section 4.2 here: https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Install.htm